# Syntax explanation of [target == t,1]

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I am reading the book : "Building Machine Learning Systems with Python". 
In the classification of Iris dates, I am having trouble understanding the syntax of :

```
plt.scatter(features[target == t,0],
                   features[target == t,1],
                   marker=marker,
                   c=c)
```

Specifically, what does `features[target == t,0]` actually mean?

Comment: `target == t` will evaluate to `True` if they are equal or `False` if they are not.  Then you just have e.g `features[True, 0]`

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, this is probably not correct in this case. It uses indexing via boolean arrays.

Comment: @cel but that is what he said!

Comment: @DanielRoseman, oh was a misunderstanding then.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Actually, that's not what he said.  A boolean array and a boolean are not the same.  See the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at [this](https://github.com/rohinip/GA_homework/blob/master/dev/iris_plots/iris_plot.py) code, it seems that `features` and `target` are both arrays and `t` is a number. Moreover, both `features` and `target` have the same number of rows.

In that case, `features[target == t, 0]` does the following:

- `target == t` creates a Boolean array of the same shape as `target` (`True` if the value is `t`, otherwise `False`).
- `features[target == t, 0]` selects those rows from `features` which correspond to `True` in the `target == t` array. The `0` specifies that the first column of `features` should be selected.

In other words, the code selects the rows of `features` for which `target` is equal to `t` and from those rows, the `0` selects the first column.

Answer (score 0):

A better explanation to this could be that this for loop splits features array into 3 different arrays , each corresponding to a particular species of Iris.
All these arrays have the 1st feature of the particular plant(instance).
This will be the output if you `print features[target==t,0]`

```
[ 5.1  4.9  4.7  4.6  5.   5.4  4.6  5.   4.4  4.9  5.4  4.8  4.8  4.3  5.8
  5.7  5.4  5.1  5.7  5.1  5.4  5.1  4.6  5.1  4.8  5.   5.   5.2  5.2  4.7
  4.8  5.4  5.2  5.5  4.9  5.   5.5  4.9  4.4  5.1  5.   4.5  4.4  5.   5.1
  4.8  5.1  4.6  5.3  5. ]
[ 7.   6.4  6.9  5.5  6.5  5.7  6.3  4.9  6.6  5.2  5.   5.9  6.   6.1  5.6
  6.7  5.6  5.8  6.2  5.6  5.9  6.1  6.3  6.1  6.4  6.6  6.8  6.7  6.   5.7
  5.5  5.5  5.8  6.   5.4  6.   6.7  6.3  5.6  5.5  5.5  6.1  5.8  5.   5.6
  5.7  5.7  6.2  5.1  5.7]
[ 6.3  5.8  7.1  6.3  6.5  7.6  4.9  7.3  6.7  7.2  6.5  6.4  6.8  5.7  5.8
  6.4  6.5  7.7  7.7  6.   6.9  5.6  7.7  6.3  6.7  7.2  6.2  6.1  6.4  7.2
  7.4  7.9  6.4  6.3  6.1  7.7  6.3  6.4  6.   6.9  6.7  6.9  5.8  6.8  6.7
  6.7  6.3  6.5  6.2  5.9]
```